# Why doesn't the Dart's Polymer package contain builder.dart?

Tags: build, dart, dart-polymer, dart-pub

Dart's guide on [Polymer](https://www.dartlang.org/polymer-dart/) suggests creating a build.dart file in the root directory. The first line is an import to polymer/builder.dart

> import 'package:polymer/builder.dart';

Since polymer.builder.dart does not exist the build file throws and errors and is thus moot. What am I doing wrong here?

My pubspec.yaml is as follow:

name:  JSONPiler
description:  A compiler written in Dart

dependencies:
  polymer: any
  poppy: any
  logging: 0.9.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using build.dart for build Dart to Javascript is outdated.

use `pub build` and `pub serve` with a transformers configuration:

```yaml
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points:
    - web/alarm.html
```

[Configuring the Built-in dart2js Transformer](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dart2js-transformer.html)

`build.dart` and polymers `builder.dart` are still supported.
I don't know why your installation can't find `builder.dart`.
The file should be in your application directory `packages/polmyer/builder.dart` (Polymer 0.10.0-pre.2)

Comment: Looks like I was on Polymer 0.9.5.
Anyways, I have used the transformers config and it works, thanks alot.